# Asymmetry in Solve (probably because of subscripts)

Tags: equation-solving, subscript

I am trying to solve this equation for $R$ and $R_Y$. The equation seems symmetrical in terms of $R$ and $R_Y$.  I don't understand why it solves fine for $R_Y$, but can't for $R$. If I replace $R_Y$ with $P$, then everything works just fine. I guess something is because of subscript use.
$$ \frac{V_1 S R}{K_1 + R} - \frac{V_2 R_Y}{K_2 + R_Y} = 0$$

Solving for $R$.

```
Solve[(Subscript[V, 1] S R)/(Subscript[K, 1] + R) - (
Subscript[V, 2] Subscript[R, Y])/(
Subscript[K, 2] + Subscript[R, Y]) == 0, R]
```

Returns the expression itself.  I guess if fails to solve for $R$.

> Solve[(R S Subscript[V, 1])/(R + Subscript[K, 1]) - (
>     Subscript[R, Y] Subscript[V, 2])/(
>     Subscript[K, 2] + Subscript[R, Y]) == 0, R]

Solving for $R_Y$

```
Solve[(R S Subscript[V, 1])/(R + Subscript[K, 1]) - (
Subscript[R, Y] Subscript[V, 2])/(
Subscript[K, 2] + Subscript[R, Y]) == 0, Subscript[R, Y]]
```

Solve for $R_Y$ just fine.

> {{Subscript[R, 
>     Y] -> -((R S Subscript[K, 2] Subscript[V, 1])/(
>      R S Subscript[V, 1] - R Subscript[V, 2] - 
>       Subscript[K, 1] Subscript[V, 2]))}}

Comment: The problem is that Mathematica thinks that `Subscript[R,Y]` is an unknown function of `R`.  Thus it can't solve the equations for `R`.  You can see this same behavior if you replace `Subscript` with an arbitrary function `f`.   Easiest solution is not to use subscripts, and instead just use things like `RY` and `V1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to avoid subscripts and the associated problems.

```
Format[R[x_: ""]] := Subscript[R, x]
Format[V[n_Integer]] := Subscript[V, n]
Format[K[n_Integer]] := Subscript[K, n]

eqn = (V[1]*S*R[])/(K[1] + R[]) - (V[2]*R[y])/(K[2] + R[y]) == 0
```

[image]

```
soln1 = Solve[eqn, R[]][[1]]
```

[image]

```
soln2 = Solve[eqn, R[y]][[1]]
```

[image]